# How to parse user input to int in console application

Tags: c#, input, int

I want to create a C# application that inputs one salesperson's item sold for the last week and calculates and displays that salesperson's earnings. The sales person receives $200 per week plus 9% of their gross sales for that week. Having been supplied a list of items sold by each salesperson and their values, how do I convert the user input to int? Everything else works fine.

```
double value1, value2, value3, value4;

value1 = 239.99;
value2 = 129.75;
value3 = 99.95;
value4 = 350.89;

Console.Write("Enter number sold of product #1: ");
int item1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter number sold of product #2: ");
int item2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter number sold of product #3: ");
int item3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Enter number sold of product #4: ");
int item4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

double sales1, sales2, sales3, sales4, totalSales;

sales1 = item1 * value1;
sales2 = item2 * value2;
sales3 = item3 * value3;
sales4 = item4 * value4;

totalSales = sales1 + sales2 + sales3 + sales4;

double commission;
int weeklyPay = 200;

commission = (9/100) * totalSales;

double salary;

salary = commission + weeklyPay;

Console.Write("Earnings this week: " + salary);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` will work. or `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` is shorter.

Comment: seems everything fine, are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

`Earnings this week` will always return `200`. This is not because the user input is not being read (see jih's answer for a more robust method of parsing a string to an int) but because of a bug:

```
commission = (9/100) * totalSales;
```

The problem is that you are doing [integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Try

```
commission = 0.09 * totalSales;
```

or

```
commission = 9.0/100.0 * totalSales;
```

The parentheses around `9/100` are redundant but are ok if they improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

Although your approach seems correct at first sight, you should cast strings into simple datatypes in a non-vexing style.

Check this (quite verbose) code:

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
int parsedValue;
if(!Int32.TryParse(userInput, out parsedValue))
{
    // Decide what to do here, parsing failed!
}
else
{
    // String format from user was valid and parsed value is in parsedValue variable.
}
```

If your are interested in a more detailed argument of why this is better coding, check Eric Lippert article about [Vexing Exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx).

Comment: OP's input parsing is okay, OP has an integer division bug. See my answer.

Comment: I addressed what I think is not okay about his code in regard to the title and question. I guess you're addressing what in the end was his motivation to ask.

Answer (score 0):

try this

> commission = ((double)9/100) * totalSales;

Comment: well the result of 9/100 is 0.09 as both 9 and 100 are integers so the result will be casted as an integer which will become 0, the decimal part is ignored. that is why the commission was always zero in OP's case. if we cast 9 to a double then the resulting number after the division will be double i.e containing the decimal portion which will give the right answer